# Open video in WMP by clicking links in IE

Tags: windows-7, video, internet-explorer, windows-media-player

How to carry the login information and/or IE browser cache to Windows Media Player?

(I apologize that the screen captures are in Traditional Chinese, as I reside in Hong Kong...)

For example, I have a video in the following URL, which requires basic authentication (login) to access.

http://h.swan.tk:8080/tmp/test/

For your testing purpose, the username is "test", and the password is "today!234".

[image: URL that requires authentication]

Using IE to open the above URL, then you can see that there is a video "life.wmv".

[image: After login, one can see a video]

The problem is that, when I click on the video link "life.wmv", it opens the WMV in the Windows Media Player, and then WMP asks me the credential information again.

[image: However, when I click in IE, WMP pops up and ask the login info again!]

Is WMP using the IE cache and/or session? If these information can be shared between IE and WMP. They should not ask me the login information again.

I look forward to your generous assistance. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried adding the website to your local intranet zone. [This question has some similar issues.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/b5fabf35-4df6-4caf-9ebf-f58ab3e47946/windows-media-player-prompts-for-enter-network-password-when-opening-from-sharepoint-2010?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

Comment: Thank you for your information. Have just tried to add the site to local intranet zone. Unfortunately, everything remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically prefixing the user name and password to the URL and loading it as a stream in Windows Media Player should have worked but, like you, it asked for credentials again. However, Open Network Stream in VLC behaved as expected using http://test:today!234@h.swan.tk:8080/tmp/test/life.wmv

Do not know what's up with WMP. Hope this approach can lead you in the right direction to a solution.

edit: additional - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/816089

Windows Media Player 9 Series Prompts User for Credentials with NTLM Authenticated Proxy

Comment: Nice find, can you just confirm that installing the fix from the KB resolved the issue?

Comment: No, I am sorry. Usually I would know for certain before I make comment but this is Microsoft! What works for me may not work for you. Also, I do not want to contaminate my Windows 7 with all the tweaks WMP does to everything and never ever start it.